# How do we specify the order of instances of a class?

Tags: uml

I want to model (UML Class Diagram) a frame.
The frame consists of two buffers each four bytes long.
The buffer is separated in three logical data units:

- byte[0], byte[ 1 ] constitute **value;**
- byte[2] is **address**
- byte[3] is **command**

The order in which they appear is something I want to express trough the model. To qualify relation as ordered, is an option, but far from enough. I explicitly want to express the information of the order in terms of memory location.

I have made an attempt to model the concept, though very poorly. Please see the attached image. The focus is onto the class `octet`, which represents the byte I am talking about.

[image]

It is the aim of the model to express such a space-time relation -

> { MSByte value, LSByte value, address, command,}

Space, because `MSByte value` is first in the memory(at the lowest location)
Time, because the frame is shifted out trough serial port `MSByte value` first.

I am new in UML modeling and the order-like information is not abundant throughout the structure diagrams I have seen. Although the order is one of the major characteristics in the definition of the word **STRUCTURE**.

Comment: N.B. Octet, not Octed :)

Comment: The English is not my strength :-), moreover StarUml doesn't have spell check :). Anyway thank you @ThomasKilian for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do it simply like this:

[image]

You can describe the ordering in a general modeling rule or in a note nearby the buffer class.

Alternatively you could dig into Superstructures about `union` but then you probably end up with things like

> derived_union_is_derived
>
> A derived union is derived.

(on p. 150)

Comment: Killian thank you for the answer.
Some questions has arisen since your answer:


- What is a General Modeling Rule?

- Is there a convention that the attributes into the attribute compartment are ordered?

- What if I want to have the attributes as a classes instead of attributes?

- How do we denote ordered classes in UML class diagram?

Comment: General modeling rule is some rule book you write yourself (e.g. red colored elements are critical). AFAIK there is no convention about ordering per se. You can type properties also as classes, no problem. You should ask a new question about the ordered classes.